# Type mismatch error when "FolderPath "(path to a folder)" is called

Tags: vbscript, type-mismatch

I'm making a .vbs that display a message box of all files and files in subfolders. Here is the code (it is part of a bigger script):

```
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

FolderPath "C:\My Documents"

Sub ProcessFolder(FolderPath)
    Set Fls = fldr.Files

    Set objFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile(outFile, True)

    For Each thing In Fls
        MsgBox thing.Path
    Next

    Set fldrs = fldr.SubFolders
    Set objFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile(outFile, True)
    For Each thing In fldrs
        MsgBox thing.Path
        ProcessFolder thing.Path
    Next
End Sub
```

When I run it, it errors on line 3 (where `FolderPath` is called), saying:

> Type mismatch: FolderPath

Comment: There is no function or procedure `FolderPath` in the code you posted. The only `FolderPath` in it is a parameter to the procedure `ProcessFolder` (which use properties of an undefined variable `fldr`).

Comment: FolderPath "C:\My Documents" is where it errors.

Comment: Yes, you mentioned that already.

Comment: So how do I fix this error? It is part of a script

Comment: Did you actually read what I wrote? You're trying to call a function/procedure `FolderPath` that isn't defined anywhere.

Comment: Sorry, I am new to VBScript. Where do I define it?

Comment: Please go find a VBScript tutorial. SO is not a place where we teach you the basics of your chosen language.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Once upon a time there used to be `SCRIPT56.CHM`  Is there a reason it is no more to be found on any MS-site you know off?

Comment: @LotPings Microsoft doesn't feature it anymore, but you can still [download it](http://download.microsoft.com/download/winscript56/Install/5.6/W982KMeXP/EN-US/scrdoc56en.exe) (probably by mistake). I'm not involved with Microsoft, though, so I can't tell you why they decided to remove the official download. Maybe because they want people to use their website instead of offline resources. Maybe because they're preparing to deprecate VBScript.

Comment: Fixed it. i got ProcessFoler and FolderPath mixed up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Folderpath="c:\windows"
```

You are missing an equal sign.

Comment: The equal sign caused it not to error with type mismatch, but it didn't do anything(no message box)

Comment: Help is at https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8247

Comment: They seem to have taken 5.6 down and put 5.7 up.